# Angular 2: capture events from ng-content

Tags: angular

Angular app structure:

```
<app><div content><a href="#" (click)="show()">click me</a></div></app>
```

Content component template:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Content component has public method `show()`, but when i click this link i get:

```
Error: EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: l_context.show is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
anonymous/ChangeDetector_AppComponent_0.prototype.handleEventInternal@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js line 10897 > Function:207:13
AbstractChangeDetector</AbstractChangeDetector.prototype.handleEvent@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8788:17
```

Basically i want to reuse page markup and put listeners on existing dom, i don't want to create additonal templates or components. Probably i'm missing something obvious.

[Planker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bp3NO8umeWudsHlFkV9r?p=preview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`show()` would resolve to the parent component of `<app>` and because it looks like `<app>` is the root component, there is no parent.

I guess the bug here is that Angular even tries to bind to the click event.
I got the impression that `<ng-content>` isn't supported at all on the root component.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858 (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6046)

**Update**

```
<h1>Angular</h1>
<div content #contentRef>
    <ui>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="contentRef.show($event)" class="link" button>link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="contentRef.show($event)" class="link" button>link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" (click)="contentRef.show($event)" class="link" button>link 3</a></li>
    </ui>
</div>
```

bindings are resolved within the component where they are declared. In the above example I explicitly redirected the reference to the `ContentComponent` by creating a template variable `#contentRef` on the target element and referring it when defining the click handler `(click)="contentRef.show($event)"`.

Even though the content is "passed" to another component using `<ng-content>` doesn't mean the scope changes. `<ng-content>` is only a projection - the elements are displayed at a different place is all, they are still "owned" by the component where they are added originally.

Comment: opps, my fault, sample code is incorrect, one moment.

Comment: there is additional content component under app which declares template with ng-content. I noticed that angular uses app context instead of content.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't really change anything in my opinion. The parent "scope" is still the parent of the root component.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i've updated description, i wish was not rushing. App contains component with ng-content template, but listeners are resolved in app.

Comment: That would only work if `<a href="#" (click)="show()">click me</a>` would be inside the template of `ContentComponent`. If `<div content><a href="#" (click)="show()">click me</a></div>` were inside the template of an Angular component you would be able to `<div content #contentRef><a href="#" (click)="#contentRef.show()">click me</a></div>` (not tried exactly like that myself yet though)

Comment: But isn't it inside? I assumed that if component has template with ng-content then component is parent of ng-content, so everything should also be resolved against this component.

Comment: It's inside the tag, but not inside the template, which means the string you pass to `template: "..."` or in the the file passed to `templateUrl: "someFile"`. Can you please create a Plunker that shows exactly what you are trying?

Comment: added planker sample.

Comment: Seems this is what you want then http://plnkr.co/edit/15Fe1mByb5jziD51xllS?p=preview (as also explained in a previous comment)

Comment: thank you, it solved my problem, is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Comment: Can't find anything. I only remember seeing it mentioned in a discussion.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `<ng-content> is only a projection - the elements are displayed at a different place is all, they are still "owned" by the component where they are added originally.`