# Capturing events emitted from components inside <ng-content>?

Tags: angular, events

I have a custom modal component which uses `<ng-content>` to transclude content:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-container',
  template: `
    <div [class]="css">
      <div [attr.id]="id" class="reveal" (open)="openModal()">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ModalContainerComponent {
    . . .
}
```

In the contents of `<ng-content>` I have a component which emits the `open` event:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login-modal',
  template: `
    <modal-container [id]="'login-modal'">
      <section>...</section>
    </modal-container>
  `,
})
export class LoginModalComponent implements OnInit {

    @Output()
    open = new EventEmitter();

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Here I am checking an ngrx store with code that is not included
        if (state.openLoginModal) {
          this.open.emit();
        }
    }

}
```

however, the `ModalContainerComponent` never receives the event.

Examples such as:

- [How to observe input element changes in ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805497/how-to-observe-input-element-changes-in-ng-content)
- [Angular 2: capture events from ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35574220/angular-2-capture-events-from-ng-content)

are coming up short. What am I doing wrong?

---

### **Update:**

Since `@Output` events don't bubble, I decided to go with a custom directive to emit the event:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: '[open-modal]',
  host: { '(click)': 'openModal()' }
})
export class OpenModalDirective {

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer
  ) {}

  openModal(): void {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      'dispatchEvent',
      [new CustomEvent('open-modal-container', { bubbles: true })]);
  }

}
```

using: [in Angular2 how to know when ANY form input field lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342890/in-angular2-how-to-know-when-any-form-input-field-lost-focus/36348311#36348311) as an example.

However, I still can't pick up the custom event in `ModalContainerComponent`:

```
@HostListener('open-modal-container')
openModalContainer(): void {
  console.log('openModal() was invoked');
}
```

I can log the click event, so that's happening, but the host listener is failing. Thoughts?

---

### Update 2

I'm abandoning this approach in favor of a shared service, but I'm running into an issue with `.next()` not providing a value to the subscriber: [Subscriber doesn't receive value from .next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865348/subscriber-doesnt-receive-value-from-next)

Comment: is it possible to provide a plunkr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the event-driven approach and went with a shared service class instead.

Answer (score 7):

You could get an instance of the login modal with `@ContentChild()` and manually subscribe to the open event

```
@Component({
    selector: 'modal-container',
    template: `
    <div [class]="css">
      <div [attr.id]="id" class="reveal" (open)="openModal()">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ModalContainerComponent {
    @ContentChild(LoginModalComponent)
    loginModal: LoginModalComponent;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.loginModal.open.subscribe((event) => {
            //Handel event here
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Then I have to add each ContentChild, of which there are several, to `ModalContainerComponent`. That seems counter-intuitive to me. I'm curious as to why the event isn't bubbling through `ng-content`

Comment: If you have multiple instances of the same class in your content that you want to get you can use `ContentChildred()` instead https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html . EventEmitter events never bubble up even if you didn't have an `ng-content`

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on rob'a answer and comment

```
@ContentChild(LoginModalComponent) private models: QueryList<LoginModalComponent>;


ngAfterViewInit() {
    let models = this.models.toArray();

    for (let key in panels) {
        let model = models[key];
        panel.open.subscribe(()=>{
            // do things
        });

    }
}
```

This works in my case, and included for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Event emitters in Angular are not bubbling up. If you want an event that bubbling up, you should create an event with [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent).
In your case the event will work only if your register it on the component itself:

```
<login-modal (open)="func()"></login-modal>
```

Comment: That's what the Angular team decide.

Comment: Brandon says what we're all thinking though.

Answer (score 0):

In my use case I find this work around

The custom component view contains **ng-content**

```
        <!-- more code -->
        <ng-template #matchCodeModal let-modal>
          <div>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <!-- more code -->
```

in the parent component I'm providing the ng-content with transclude content

```
        <fw-match-code #match [(value)]="tc.filters.idSostanza" (enterPressed)="tc.refresh()">
          <app-sostanze popup="true" (selected)="match.onSelect($event)"></app-sostanze>
        </fw-match-code>
```

I needed to capture **selected** event emitted by **app-sostanze** component inside **fw-match-code**.

I managed to do that associating a template variable called **#match** to **fw-match-code** and the triggering  **match.onSelect($event)** on the component behind the view:

```
   export class MatchCodeComponent implements OnInit {
        //...
        onSelect(data: any): void {
            this.modal?.dismiss(data);
        }
        //...
   }
```